# Loading a newer version of jQuery within WordPress

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I've read about the WP enqueue_script() function, but if I wanted to use a newer version of jQuery than what my WP installation is using, can I load it through this & WP will use the latest version? or will it load both? or what will happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me advise you that this is a bad idea. When we release WP, we test the scripts that ship with it to make sure they work. When jQuery 1.5 came out a while ago, a lot of sites broke because people were loading the "latest" version of jQuery from the Google API. WP wasn't tested with that version yet, and it killed a lot of the admin screen as a result. Just be aware of what can happen when you start overriding the tested parts of WordPress with your own stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the default jQuery url, do:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'your custom url', ... );
```

Then call `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );` as usual.

Note that various pages in the WP admin might not be compatible with never versions of jQuery, not to mention plugin scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can (de)register the builtin jquery with the following functions:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
```

And register a new jquery library:

```
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.4', true);
```

Comment: The stable is 1.5.1 already. :) Also for external script it is better to pass `null` for version - that will suppress version tag on output and improve caching aspects.

Comment: The code example was a bit old ;). Thanks for the hint with the caching, I will look into this.